# Split a collection based on Boolean value into 2 collections Scala

Tags: scala, collections, filter

I want to perform only one transformation where I end up with a tuple of `(Array[Person], Array[Person])` based on meeting a conditional statement where the split is based on `true, false`.

So something like `.filter` that splits the output based on `true, false` instead of only `true`.

I currently have this but want to do it in one statement.

```
case class Person(age: Int)

val persons: Array[Person] = Array(Person(15), Person(17), Person(30), Person(35))

val adults: Array[Person] = persons.filter(p => isAdult(p.age))
val kids: Array[Person] = persons.filter(p => !isAdult(p.age))

def isAdult(age: Int): Boolean = age > 18
```

Is it possible with some collection API to do this in one operation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, like this

```
persons.partition(p => isAdult(p.age))
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use `partition` method.
Like
`persons.partition(p => isAdult(p.age))`.